# Event loop - Trigger on socket connection

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn more about event loops and to fully understand it so i have tried to make something basic. I'm on Mac so i'm using **kqueue**.

The idea is to trigger the event loop only on new socket connections. The event loop get triggered on socket connection, but it wont stop on the next cycle. It keep printing after the first connections:

```
NEW CLIENT
NEW CLIENT
NEW CLIENT
NEW CLIENT
NEW CLIENT
```

etc...

It supossed to only print " NEW CLIENT " on new socket connection.

Here is the full source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>


struct kevent e;
static struct sockaddr_in server;
static int server_fd, queue;


static void event_server_listen (int port) {
    int err, flags;

    queue = kqueue();

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    int opt_val = 1;
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));

    err = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));

    flags = fcntl(server_fd, F_GETFL, 0);


    err = fcntl(server_fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);


    err = listen(server_fd, SOMAXCONN);

}


static void event_change (int ident, int filter, int flags, void *udata) {

    e.ident = ident;
    e.filter = filter;
    e.flags = flags;
    e.fflags = 0;
    e.data = 0;
    e.udata = udata;
}

static void event_loop () {

    while (1) {


        int nev = kevent(queue, &e, 1, &e, 1, NULL);

        if (nev == -1) { exit(0); }


        printf("NEW CLIENT\n");


    }
}





int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {


    int port = 8899;

    event_server_listen(port);
    event_change(server_fd, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD | EV_ENABLE, NULL);
    event_loop();

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why that is happening and show me how to fix it please?

Comment: Why do you save the `err` value but never do anything with it? did you remove the lines handling the errors? Keep them, they will not bother us.

Comment: Yes i removed to not post large code :-) so we can focus on the problem

Comment: You never call `accept()` on `socket_fd` to finish establishing the new connection, so the socket is always showing up as readable since it has a pending connection.

Comment: Shawn! that give sense  :D - e.udata most contain the accept function? can you show how to extract it from the event_loop??

Comment: Adding to @Shawn if you used [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) then you can make a distintion between `accept()` and when the socket is readable. I've implemented such event system in the past.

Comment: Select have a timeout and you have to loop it to check, but kqueue will notify you about changes

Comment: Extract? You mean remove the listening socket from the kevent queue? You can do that with `EV_DELETE` (Or `EV_DISABLE`). There's also `EV_ONESHOT` to only trigger the notification once. But the usual workflow would be, when the listening socket comes up as readable, to accept a new socket from it, and add that to the kqueue so you know when there's data waiting to be read from it, and leave the listening socket in the kqueue so that you get notified of additional connections.

Comment: I'd also suggest, if you're just using sockets and not any of kqueue's other notification types, to use a higher level event loop library like libevent, libev, libuv, etc. to manage things. Adds handy features you'd have to write yourself otherwise, and portable to non-BSD OSes.

Comment: Thank you to both :-) it works now after accepting the clients ! thank you will look the event loop library  it's just so nice to try make it ourself